# JS - Sum Of Two Arrays where arrays can be of unequal length

Tags: javascript

I need function like this.

```
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
  return totalArray
};

sum([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]) // [6,8,10,12,9]
```

I tried it this way:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 100];
var sum = array1.map((num, idx) => num + array2[idx]); // [6,8,10,12]
```

Comment: I try this way.
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [5,6,7,8, 100];

var sum = array1.map( (num, idx) => num + array2[idx]); // [6,8,10,12]

Comment: @MarineKhloyan you should have put this in your question, along with what didn't work. The point is we want to help you fix your problems if you can't but we don't want to do the job in your place. If you fix your question please tell us so we reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try this way.
>
> ```
>  var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
>  var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 100];
>  var sum = array1.map((num, idx) => num + array2[idx]); // [6,8,10,12]
> ```

Very close, but `map` will stop at the end of `array1`, so you won't get the subsequent entries from `array2`. Just pick the longer of the two arrays, then handle the fact that the other array may not have an entry at `arrayX[idx]`. You can do that with the `|| 0` idiom:

```js
function sum(array1, array2) {
  var a, b;
  if (array1.length > array2.length) {
    a = array1;
    b = array2;
  } else {
    a = array2;
    b = array1;
  }
  return a.map((num, idx) => num + (b[idx] || 0));
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 100]));
```

Alternately, you can use the new (but polyfill-able) [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create the result array and use the callback to build the entries:

```js
function sum(array1, array2) {
  return Array.from(
    {length: Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)},
    (_, i) => (array1[i] || 0) + (array2[i] || 0)
  );
}

console.log(sum([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 100]));
```

[Mosho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170963/157247) is wonderfully simple, though.

Answer (score 4):

First you can get an array out of the function's `arguments` using [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), then sort it by array's `length` using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and finally [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the result array

Code:

```js
const sum =(...arrays) => arrays
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
  .reduce((a, c) => a.map((n, i) => n + (c[i] || 0)) || c)

// two arrays
const resultTwoArrays = sum([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
console.log(resultTwoArrays) // [6, 8, 10, 12, 9]

// three arrays or more...
const resultThreeArrays = sum([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2])
console.log(resultThreeArrays) // [7, 10, 10, 12, 9]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of being unpopular due to using a loop:

```
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
    let totalArray = [];
    const totalLength =  Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
        totalArray[i] = (arr1[i] || 0) + (arr2[i] || 0);
    }
    return totalArray;
}
```

The `|| 0` handles the possibility the array doesn't have an entry at `i`, because if it doesn't, the result of `arrX[i]` is `undefined`, and `undefined || 0` is `0`.

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Find the long and short array according to length. Iterate the short array with `Array.map()`, and take the value from the long array. Then add the leftovers from the long array using [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
  const [l, s] = arr1.length >= arr2.length ? [arr1, arr2] : [arr2, arr1];
    
  return s.map((n, i) => n + l[i])
        .concat(l.slice(s.length));
};

console.log(sum([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are we code golfing this? Here's a generator solution.

```js
const summer = function*(a, b, i=0) {
  while(i < a.length || i < b.length) yield (a[i] || 0)  + (b[i++] || 0);
};
const sum = (a, b) => [...summer(a,b)];

console.log(sum([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9])) // [6,8,10,12,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `map()`:

```js
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
  var [a1, a2] = arr1.length > arr2.length ? [arr1, arr2] : [arr2, arr1]
  var totalArray = a1.map(function(i, idx){
    i = (i + a2[idx] || i + 0); 
    return i;
  })
  return totalArray;
};

console.log(sum([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9])) // [6,8,10,12,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom logic something like this:

```js
function sum(arr1, arr2) {
  var length, selectedArray, nonSelectedArray;
  if(arr1.length>arr2.length){
   length = arr1.length;
   selectedArray = arr2;
   nonSelectedArray = arr1;
  }else {
   length = arr2.length;
   selectedArray = arr1;
   nonSelectedArray = arr2;
  }
  var totalArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
    if(selectedArray[i]){
      totalArray.push(selectedArray[i] + nonSelectedArray[i]);
    } else {
      totalArray.push(nonSelectedArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return totalArray
};

var res = sum([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9]);
console.log(res);
```